# jQuery mouseover or hover help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this button, text: *Add to bag* css hover:{background-color:#A9885D; color:#fff;}

With the following jQuery code, once the button is clicked the text *Add to bag* changes to *Added* with a green background color and then -

reverts the *Added* text back to its original *Add to bag* text after 5 seconds.

challenge: only the text *Added* reverts back to *Add to bag* after 5 seconds but not the hover:background color and text color. how can I revert not only the text but also the hover background-color and text color as well?

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
var element = jQuery("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added");
element.text("ADDED");
setTimeout(function() {
    element.text("ADD TO BAG");
    element.css('background-color', '#F0EFEB');
    element.css('color', '#A9885D');
}, 5 * 1000);
```

I tried element.css.hover('background-color', '#A9885D'); NO CHANGE
Also tried .mouseover function but did't work, am new to jQuery :)

Comment: Hi Miraj, please add a [mcve] to the question; the code you've shared is not quite enough for us to reproduce the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element.css('background-color', '#F0EFEB');
element.css('color', '#A9885D');
```

The above mentioned code should work, Could you Inspect Element in chrome and check if your CSS property are overridden

Comment: Hi, the above code is working but when i point the cursor on the button there is no hover background color, for instance, on css i have background-color and color then i have a hover: background color.

Here i have the background color and text color and it is working but i can't get a hover:background color

Comment: $("#somecontent").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
}).mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).css("background-color", "#F0EFEB").;
});

Comment: create another jquery event   for mouuseenter and Mouuseleaving  and add css within the method to reflect the change

Comment: Thank you for mentioning if the CSS is overridden, once i started reading my css, I found a solution and used added:hover with !important; which worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

$("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added").mouseleave(function() {
  $(element).css('background-color', '#F0EFEB');
});

$("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added").mouseover(function() {
  $(element).css('background-color', '#A9885D');
});

Comment: I could not upvote your answer, the system is telling me that i need more reputation before i can upvote stuff in publick. Thank you!